# Selenium wait/sleep command

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Why does this Selenium C# code doesn't wait till the elements are loaded ?!

```
_fireFoxWebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
```

I alternatively used `Thread.Sleep(5000);`
Neither it does! could someone explain this to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, the test will wait only 5 seconds and back the execution. If you need to wait for an element while it does not exist or is not visible, you shoud to use `WebDriverWait`. Example:

```
var timeout = 10000; // in milliseconds
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("your-selector")));
```

Also, if you need to wait the page loads, you can use the code:

```
var timeout = 10000; // in milliseconds
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

In both cases, 10 seconds is the limit time to find the elements. If no one element has found in this time, the test dont will pass. Else if an element was found in 5 seconds, the code does not will wait all the seconds remain, it will proceed to the next code line.

This kind of wait us useful because you don't need to wait all the limit time to find an element, only the necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if we want to wait until the element should be clickable means, we can use following WebDriverWait method :wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element))

For Example :

```
 WebElement ele=driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));
 WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 50); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
```